# Can someone explain this singly linked last line of code below? <"Node data: %s>" % self.data

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

```python
class Node:

    def _init_(self, data, next_node = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node

    def _rept_self(self):
 
        return "<Node data: %s>" % self.data
```

Can someone please explain to me the last line of code?

Comment: It returns a string `"<Node data: %s>"` where `%s` is replaced with the value of `self.data`. A better version would be `"return f"<Node data: {self.data}>"`

Comment: That is an old-school string interpolation.

Comment: This is old style of Python formatting.  See https://blog.finxter.com/string-formatting-vs-format-vs-formatted-string-literal/

Answer (score 3):

This is an old method of string formatting in Python, which is inspired by C syntax.
The %s is a placeholder which represents a string, and the variable placed after the % will be used in the place of the %s.

A more intuitive syntax for this would be using an fstring, where variables can be written in curly brackets if an f is placed before the start of a string:

```
return f"<Node data: {self.data}>"
```